# How to compare a string against multiple other strings

Tags: ruby

Is there a method that let me compare one String with multiple others in Ruby? I really would like to do something like this:

```
myString.eql?(["string1","string2","string3"])
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
["string1","string2","string3"].include? myString
```

Comment: that's not equality comparison

Comment: @Filippos: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that if myString is "s" then you will get true regadless. Instead OP asked equality. It should return true only if myString is one of "string1", "string2" or "string3". @mipadi

Comment: @Filippos: No, if `myString` is `"s"` then the above code will return `false`.

Answer (score 15):

You could use [`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002203) to see if the array includes the string:

```
%w(string1 string2 string3).include?(myString)
```

Comment: That word separator is so, so neat.

Answer (score 13):

I find myself wanting this a lot, so I added a String method to be able to do it more idiomatically:

```
class String
  def among?(*array)
    array.flatten.include?(self)
  end
end
```

Then

```
myString.among?("string1","string2","string3")
```