# Check if any of multiple strings exist in a string

Tags: javascript

I need to check if any of a set of strings exists in one main string.

Currently I'm using an array with a for loop to check each string.

Is there a simpler way, like this solution for ruby which I've come across on - [How to compare a string against multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770316/how-to-compare-a-string-against-multiple-other-strings)

```
["string1","string2","string3"].include? myString
```

Comment: A regex? `RegExp(strings.join('|')).test(myString)`

Comment: unfortunately with this string19 will return true for string1 but this works : matchfound = RegExp("^(" +strings.join("|")+")$").test(myString);
basically checking against ^(string1|string2|string3)$ instead of string1|string2|string3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How complex is your for loop? This is what loops exist for. Assuming your set of strings are an array called `setOfStrings` and your main string is in a variable called `mainString`:

```
var stringExists = false;
var setOfStrings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];

for(var i =0;i < setOfStrings.length; i++){
  if(mainString.indexOf(setOfStrings[i]) != -1)
      stringExists = true;
}
```

It might not be as terse as your Ruby construct, but it's pretty darned common.

Answer (score 2):

A did a little experiment and found that the following worked fine. The only overhead is the generation of the regexps for each element of the array. If `check` is zero or above, one of the strings was found.

```
if (!('included' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.included = function() {
    return arr.map(function (item) {
      var regex = new RegExp(item, 'g');
      if (regex.test(str)) return true;
      return false;
    }).indexOf(true);
  };
}
```

To return a boolean instead of a number just change it to:

```
if (!('included' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.included = function () {
    var regex, found = false;
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
      regex = new RegExp(this[i], 'g');
      if (regex.test(str)) { found = true; break; }
    }
    return found;
  };
}

var found = arr.included(str);
```

This is an edit of my previous answer because I realised I hadn't actually answered the question :)

Comment: hi andy thanks but i still have some difficulty grasping regex, so was actually looking for a simple to remember solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be simple and pretty fast:

```
const arrayOfStrings = ["string1","string2","string3"];
const myStringExists = arrayOfStrings.some(item => myString.includes(item));
```